# Regex for parsing a search field for keywords and tags ([])

Tags: javascript, regex, search

I'm trying to implement a search input similar to Stackoverflow's (in node.js/javascript).

- Parse tags delimited by brackets
- Parse keywords delimited by spaces

However, I don't understand regex at all. I don't even know if regexs are the way to go.

For example:

```js
search field [search][search-query] [search-string]
// keywords: ['search', 'field']
// tags: ['search', 'search-query', 'search-string']
```

Unfortunately, I find it additionally difficult to search any help on this since searching for `regex search tags` returns HTML questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you'll need something like this:

```
/(?:\[([^\]]*)\]|([^\s]+))/g
```

You can apply it repeatedly (e.g. using the Javascript exec method) and then extract values from the first and second capturing groups to capture tags and keywords respectively.

To explain:

The outermost () brackets enclose a choice of matching either a tag (enclosed by square brackets []) or a keyword (not enclosed by square brackets). The ?: bit excludes this choice bit from a capturing group since we need to know specifically whether the matched expression is a tag or keyword and so need a separate capturing group for each.

The next bit [([^]]*)] matches a tag: the opening and closing square brackets need to be escaped with a backslash to make them literals. The bit within the square brackets is enclosed in normal brackets () to capture the text within in the first capturing group. The [^...] bit matches anything except what is listed after the caret - so in this case anything except the closing square bracket. This is repeated greedily using the *.

The | separates the choice and then we have the matching expression for a keyword: ([^\s]+). Again this is in brackets to make the results appear in a capturing group. This time we are matching anything except for whitespace one or more times.

Finally the /g is the global modifier so that all occurrences are matched.

Comment: hey this is pretty awesome. i'm going to try to figure out what youre doing in a bit. Some questions: 1) I'm assuming the output is `[string matched, tag string, word string]`. 2) Edge case: `word[tag]` should return `word` and `[tag]`. Is that an easy fix?

Comment: there's also something like `[unfinished`, `unfinished]`, and `[tag[crap]]` but we can just ignore those

Comment: I've edited the answer to include an explanation of the regular expression. Hopefully this should be enough to get you going...

Answer (score 0):

The following code retrieves the tags from the string as an array:

```
var tags= "search field [search][search-query] [search-string]".match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
// tags= ["search", "search-query", "search-string"]
```